# WPF WebBrowser - call methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wpf, communication

I'm developing a WPF application with only a WebBrowser that launch a HTML page with JavasCript. I also have some C# methods.

I'm looking for a good way to launch my C# methods in JavaScript, with parameters and if possible callbacks.

For now, I have JavaScript methods that navigate to special URL like "myApp://mymethod?param1=value&param2=value" and in the "Navigating" event of the webBrowser, I check the URL and call the method that I need with the parameters.

This solution works but the size of the URL is limited. How can I send heavier data ? (custom headers data, POST, cookies, local storage or anything else I don't know... :) )

I can't use window.external because in the end I will use Xamarin to do a cross-platforms app. WebBrowser will be for Windows, but IOS use UIWebView that dosen't support window.external ( stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/… ) so i need a solution that works everywhere and the custom URL has a size limit.

If somebody has a solution...

Comment: I have never used it but you can look for ObjectForScripting property on WebBrowser object.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to say that it should be multi-platform at the end (I will use Xamarin for IOS and android). Si i will have a "WebBrowser" on windows, a "WebView" on android, ... So I'm looking for a solution that will work everywhere...

Comment: Well i see only 2 possibilities (but sure there much more). Develop with phone gap or use websockets. There are some WebSocket implementations in C#. And you will be able to exchange data in json format. Here you have an article about Websockets and C# http://divyen.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/html5-developing-websocket-server-using-c-sharp-dot-net/

Comment: You can just build a low-end HTTP server into your code and host it on a local port. As Didier suggested, you could then use JSON to facilitate client/server data transfer.

Comment: Thanks again for the answers. In fact, I didn't want to use PhoneGap, but only implement a simple version of the PhoneGap principle. I will check Websockets

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [How to: Implement Two-Way Communication Between DHTML Code and Client Application Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx)

Basically you need to use `window.external` object in your scripting code to access public properties and methods

HTML Code:

```
<button onclick="window.external.Test('called from script code')">
    call client code from script code
</button>
```

C# Code in your WPF code:

```
public void Test(String message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
}
```

Communication between WPF and JavaScript requires full trust, so you will need to add following code:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MainWindow
{
        public void Test(String message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! In fact, I didn't want to use window.external because in the end I will use Xamarin to do a cross-platforms app. WebBrowser will be for Windows, but IOS use UIWebView that dosen't support window.external ( http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/ ) so i needed a solution that works everywhere and the custom URL has a size limit

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Yes, you are right for cross-platform this won't work.

Comment: No idea how I could do that ? Maybe by adding a custom header to the current page and read it in c#...